# Easy Bib is no longer installing

Tags: gsuite-addons

Easy Bib is a valuable tool that we use in our English Classes.  In the past it has installed easily. It will no longer install for our students and has become difficult for our teachers to install as well.  What has changed and how do we get approval for students to use this add on?

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on the problems you are encountering? This seems more of a Super User question than a Stack Overflow question, but I will attempt to help.

Comment: As the students attempt to add EasyBib to GoogleDocs it tells them they need to have admin approval.  Our admins are not blocking the add on.  We have tried clearing the browser, clearing cookies, updating the Chromebooks,  and nothing has worked.  One of our teachers had previously installed EasyBib and when she got on this morning, it was gone.  It would not install until she received an email verifying her identity, then it installed again.

Comment: What monitoring software are you using?

Comment: We are a school District, so our monitoring is done through the main office.  They have not blocked any apps or add ons until recently, when they blocked all of them, then changed their minds and opened it all up again to all add ons and apps for Chromebooks.  This is when the problem began.  They are no longer blocking any apps or add ons, but this add on will not work.

Comment: Or email me at jonathankurtz@protonmail.com

This problem could have several causes, and I would rather not discuss them through comments, you know?